# How to get the same appearance of an end note in endnotes and in enotez?

Tags: endnotes, enotez

I have end notes generated with the package `endnotes` and now I would like to stop using `endnotes` and start using `enotez`.

My end notes rendered with `endnotes` look like this:
[image]

while the same end note rendered with `enotez` looks like this:
[image]

There are some subtle differences that at this moment I do not care about, my goal is to get the number of the note (in this case the blue `3`) in an upper position and without the final dot. Is it possible? And how?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true]{enotez}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolor}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=linkcolor,citecolor=linkcolor,
            filecolor=linkcolor,urlcolor=linkcolor}
\let\note=\endnote

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nunc nisl, egestas non viverra at, sagittis eu mauris. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur malesuada gravida dui, ac dapibus libero auctor vel. Nam eu fermentum justo. Mauris sed aliquam mi. Sed eleifend, erat quis dictum sagittis, elit odio pretium dolor, eu semper dui sapien sit amet justo. In consectetur lacinia diam at venenatis.\note{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nunc nisl, egestas non viverra at, sagittis eu mauris. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur malesuada gravida dui, ac dapibus libero auctor vel. Nam eu fermentum justo. Mauris sed aliquam mi. Sed eleifend, erat quis dictum sagittis, elit odio pretium dolor, eu semper dui sapien sit amet justo. In consectetur lacinia diam at venenatis.
}
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Output of the MWE:
[image]

Comment: A starter document, compilable, would help to help you

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the `enotez` package should offer this style as an option. However, you can create it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backref=true]{enotez}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}

\definecolor{linkcolor}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=linkcolor,
  citecolor=linkcolor,
  filecolor=linkcolor,
  urlcolor=linkcolor
}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}
 {
  number = \makebox[0pt][r]{\textsuperscript{#1}},
  format = \indent\normalfont,
 }

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nunc nisl, egestas non viverra at, 
sagittis eu mauris. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos 
himenaeos. Curabitur malesuada gravida dui, ac dapibus libero auctor vel. Nam eu fermentum justo. 
Mauris sed aliquam mi. Sed eleifend, erat quis dictum sagittis, elit odio pretium dolor, eu semper dui 
sapien sit amet justo. In consectetur lacinia diam at venenatis.\endnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nunc nisl, egestas non viverra at, sagittis eu mauris. Class 
aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur 
malesuada gravida dui, ac dapibus libero auctor vel. Nam eu fermentum justo. Mauris sed aliquam mi. Sed 
eleifend, erat quis dictum sagittis, elit odio pretium dolor, eu semper dui sapien sit amet justo. In 
consectetur lacinia diam at venenatis.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nunc nisl, egestas non viverra at, 
sagittis eu mauris. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos 
himenaeos. Curabitur malesuada gravida dui, ac dapibus libero auctor vel. Nam eu fermentum justo. 
Mauris sed aliquam mi. Sed eleifend, erat quis dictum sagittis, elit odio pretium dolor, eu semper dui 
sapien sit amet justo. In consectetur lacinia diam at venenatis.\endnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nunc nisl, egestas non viverra at, sagittis eu mauris. Class 
aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur 
malesuada gravida dui, ac dapibus libero auctor vel. Nam eu fermentum justo. Mauris sed aliquam mi. Sed 
eleifend, erat quis dictum sagittis, elit odio pretium dolor, eu semper dui sapien sit amet justo. In 
consectetur lacinia diam at venenatis.}

\printendnotes[custom]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works great with 

number = \textsuperscript{#1}

Why do we need to put it in \makebox[0pt][r]){ } ?

Comment: @SphericalTriangle In order to right align the numbers in case they have more than one digit.